# How to aggregate values across different columns in PySpark (or eventually SQL)?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's consider the following input data

```
| incremental_id | session_start_id | session_end_id | items_bought |
|----------------|------------------|----------------|--------------|
| 1              | a                | b              | 1            |
| 2              | z                | t              | 7            |
| 3              | b                | c              | 0            |
| 4              | c                | d              | 3            |
```

Where:

- Each row represents a user session
- Each session records a start/end session id
- We know the first 3 rows are associated to the same user because `session_end_id = session_start_id`. The 4th row is instead related to a second user

I want to be able to aggregate the above data so that I can get:

- The first customer has bought 4 items
- The second customer has bought 7 items

How could this be done in PySpark (or eventually in pure SQL)? I would like to avoid using UDFs in PySpark, but it's ok if that's the only way.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit:**
I have update the example dataframe, the `incremental_id` alone cannot be used to order the rows as consecutive sessions

Comment: AFAI can see, two records in sequence can be associated by pulling value from previous row but I don't see how 3+ records can be associated in query alone. I expect UDF will be needed.

Comment: @jxc I think b.a. is not like that. It is rather `5,d,e,1` I assume.

Comment: looks like a typical question using [graphframe.connectedComponents](https://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/user-guide.html#connected-components). or if the sample is just part of group, use pandas_udf with the same method in networkx.

Answer (score 1):

Common Table Expressions are part of [SQL:1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:1999).

Using CTE, we can use the below query

```
WITH cte(session_start_id, session_end_id, items_bought) AS (
  select session_start_id, session_end_id, items_bought from user_session where session_start_id not in (
    select session_end_id from user_session)
UNION ALL
select a.session_start_id, b.session_end_id, b.items_bought from cte a 
  inner join user_session b on a.session_end_id = b.session_start_id)
  select session_start_id, sum(items_bought) from cte group by (session_start_id)
```

**Explanation:**

- In the anchor query, select all the records that does not have a parent. (i.e., no other records ends with current session_start_id)
- Recursively, join the cte's session_end_id with session_start_id from the table.
- Group the records and return the result.

**SQL Fiddle link:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ac98a/4/0
(*Note:* Used *Oracle* in fiddle. But any DB engine that supports CTE should work).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work but unfortunately I'm using prestodb and the specific version doesn't support recursive WITH statements as the query you suggested. So unfortunately I can't use your proposed approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PySpark version

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# create a window over the full data so we can lag the session end id
win = Window().partitionBy().orderBy("incremental_id")

# This is logic to indicate a user change
df = df.withColumn('user_boundary', F.lag(F.col("session_end_id"), 1).over(win) != F.col("session_start_id"))
df = df.withColumn('user_boundary', F.when(F.col("user_boundary").isNull(), F.lit(False)).otherwise(F.col("user_boundary")))

# Now create an artificial user id
df = df.withColumn('user_id', F.sum(F.col("user_boundary").cast(IntegerType())).over(win))

# Aggregate
df.groupby('user_id').agg(F.sum(F.col("items_bought")).alias("total_bought")).show()

+-------+------------+
|user_id|total_bought|
+-------+------------+
|      0|           4|
|      1|           7|
+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this solution with the lag(1) uses the assumption that `incremental_id` is indicative of subsequent sessions from the same user. I added that just for context but it should work regardless of that. I'm updating the example dataframe to make this more explicit

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access temp table creation and affected row count metadata then you can port this:

```
insert into #CTESubs
select
    session_start_id,
    session_end_id,
    items_bought
from #user_session
WHERE
    session_start_id not in (select session_end_id from #user_session)

while(@@ROWCOUNT <> 0)
begin
    insert into #CTESubs
    select distinct
        p.session_start_id,
        c.session_end_id,
        c.items_bought
    from #user_session c
        inner join #CTESubs p on c.session_start_id = p.session_end_id
    WHERE
        p.session_start_id not in (select session_end_id from #user_session) 
        and c.session_end_id not in (select session_end_id from #CTESubs)
end

select
    session_start_id,
    sum(items_bought) items_bought
from #CTESubs
group by 
    session_start_id;
```